# How to set item programatically in tablerow where column & row width and count is not fix?

Tags: android, android-tablelayout, tablerow, tablecolumn

I used `TableLayout` to show data with fixed column size but `coloumnElement` is going off the screen, like :
[image]

I just want to set data just like showing in the image below.

[image]

Comment: Can you show what is happening in your case?

Comment: I would suggest to use a different layout than TableLayout. You can use LinearLayout or RelativeLayout to achieve the expected view.

Comment: That looks like a `FlowLayout` in a `ScrollView`. Android doesn't have a `FlowLayout` built in, but there are [several examples of how to do it here already](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bandroid%5d%20flowlayout).